# Postgresql - Find overlapping time ranges for different users in the same session and present them as pairs

Tags: database, postgresql, pg

I have a table which has records of sessions a players have played in a group music play. (music instruments)

so if a user joins a session, and leaves, there is one row created.  If they join even the same session 2x, then two rows are created.

Table: music_sessions_user_history

```
| Column  | Type | Default|
| --- | --- | ---|---
| id  | character varying(64) | uuid_generate_v4()|
| user_id | user_id | |
| created_at | timestamp without time zone | now()|
| session_removed_at | timestamp without time zone | |
| max_concurrent_connections | integer |
| music_session_id|character varying(64)|
```

This table is basically the amount of time a user was in a given session. So you can think of it as a timerange or tsrange in PG. The max_concurrent_connections which is a count of the number of users who were in the session at once.

so the query at it's heart needs to find overlapping time ranges for different users in the same session; and to then count them up as a pair that played together.

The query needs to do this: It tries to report each user that played in a music session with others - and who those users were

So for example, if a userA played with userB, and that's the only data in the database, then two rows would be returned like:

```
| User  | Other users in the session |
| --- | --- |
|userA | [userB] |
|userB | [userA] |
```

But if userA played with both userB and UserC, then three rows would be like:

```
| User  | Other users in the session |
| --- | --- |
|userA | [userB, userC]|
|userB | [userA, userC]|
|userC | [userA, userB]|
```

Any help of constructing this query is much appreciated.

update:

I am able to get overlapping records using this query.

```
select m1.user_id, m1.created_at, m1.session_removed_at, m1.max_concurrent_connections, m1.music_session_id
from music_sessions_user_history m1
where exists (select 1
              from music_sessions_user_history m2
              where tsrange(m2.created_at, m2.session_removed_at, '[]') && tsrange(m1.created_at, m1.session_removed_at, '[]')
                and m2.music_session_id = m1.music_session_id
                and m2.id <> m1.id);
```

Need to find a way to convert these results in to pairs.

Comment: i think, a self join with the required condition would be enough. also consider converting the two timestamp fields into one tsrange field. this way you can && operator for overlap control. also indexing would be easier

Answer (score 1):

1. create a cursor and for each fetched record determine which other records intersect using a between time of start and end time.
2. append the intersecting results into a temporary table
3. select the results of the temporary table